# The view does not show up

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to show a *ProgressView* when the *Button* is pressed and the *user.showLoginProgress* property is set, which is declared as published. However, the new value of the property does not seem to trigger the *LoginView* to refresh, so the *ProgressView* does not show up:

```
struct LoginView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var user : User

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Button("Login", action: {
         user.credentials.showLoginProgress=true  // @Published
      })
      if user.credentials.showLoginProgress{
        ProgressView()  // never shows up
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The user is global:

```
var user : User = User()

@main
struct app1App: App {

@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

 var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        MainView().environmentObject(user)
    }
 }
}
```

and is defined as:

```
class User : ObservableObject{
  @Published var credentials = Login()
}
```

while the *credentials* is:

```
class Login : ObservableObject {
  @Published var showLoginProgress : Bool = false
}
```

Could anyone point out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: how about using `if user.showLoginProgress {ProgressView()}`

Comment: Try working dog support Ukraine method because I thought the same thing too. If it still does not work, show us your User class.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine There was a typo in the question - now it's fixed, but the problem still exists. Any second-look suggestions? Слава Україні!

Comment: show us your `User` class and how you pass it to the `LoginView`. All works well in my tests.

Comment: well there's your problem, do not **nest** ObservableObject, it is a recipe for troubles.

Comment: Put the variable for the user inside the struct. Not outside there could be a conflict there.

Comment: Re-structure your code to use only one (or more) separate `ObservableObject`.
 You could also just make: `struct Login { var showLoginProgress: Bool = false }`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I see your point, but I also have some other variables in the _Login_ struct that are bounded to the View, and that must be ObservableObject. On the other hand, I need to nest it, so that some other variables could be accessible by the parent class, which is the EnvironmentObject, and must be ObservableObject? Am I wrong?

Comment: yes you are. Do not **nest** ObservableObject.
 
 Typically you would have a `class UserManager: ObservableObject {...}` where you
 have a `@Published var user = User()` with `User` a `struct`. This `UserManager` would
 include the login `functions` to do all your login etc... In other words, re-structure your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like this approach, to re-structure your `User` and `Login`, where
there is only one `ObservableObject` and the login functions are in it.

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var manager = UserManager()
    var body: some View {
        LoginView().environmentObject(manager)
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: UserManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if manager.user.isAuthorised {
                Text(manager.user.name + " is logged in")
            }
            Button("Login", action: {
                manager.doLogin()
            })
            if manager.showLoginProgress {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
    }
}

class UserManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user = User()
    @Published var showLoginProgress = false
    @Published var someOtherVar = ""
    
    func doLogin() {
        showLoginProgress = true
        // ...
        // simulated login
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.user.name = "Mickey Mouse"
            self.user.isAuthorised = true
            self.showLoginProgress = false
        }
    }
}

struct User: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name = ""
    var isAuthorised = false
  //  var credentials: Credentials
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the _User_ does not have to be ObservableObject because since it is a @Published property in the _UserManager_, it will be automatically observed? I need my _UserManager_ as a global variable because there are some methods that should be accessible by the App and the Scene Delegates. With that setting, the _UserManeger_ is an environmentObject in every View (not @StateObject), and my view still does not refresh (. Once change a textfield content, the view refreshes and shows the ProgressView() as well.

Comment: You can easily bring `UserManager` to your `App` level, if that is what you want.
 
 The code in my answer works well, it shows the `ProgressView`
 when the `Button` is pressed (your question).
 
 If you have other `Views` that you do not show, and that do not refresh
 it's probably because you are not using `UserManager` the correct way.
 
 The `environmentObject` is just a convenient way to pass the `UserManager`,
 you can also pass it like any other variable. In that case declare it as a `@ObservedObject` in the
 receiving `View`.

Comment: Ok - the code works now. The problem was (referencing your solution) that my _User()_  was defined as `class User {`, whereas in your example it is defined as `struct User: Identifiable, Hashable {`. So switching from _class_ to _struct_ fixed the problem. Would you mind explaining why it did not want to refresh the view when using a _class_, but works as expected when using a _struct_? Also, it works without `Identifiable, Hashable` - why would it be better to use them?

Comment: There are many tutorials and info about  reference type `class` vs value type `struct` on the net and SO.
You could use a `class` for `User` (not recomended), then you would have to do the (objectWillChange.send()) updates yourself, whereas with a `struct` it is done for you. Ask a new question to find other explanations on this subject.

`Identifiable` and `Hashable` makes identifying a particular user easier for the views. Since you only have one user, 
as you find out, it works without it.  See also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable/